# Online Judge Pashmak and Flowers gives runtime error

Tags: c++

I am attempting to solve this Pashmak and Flowers Problem http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/459/B

The online judge gives me runtime error on test 4?

Any ideas?

I tried many test cases..

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a[1000];
int n;
int minimum=0x3f3f3f3f; //if left without that number, the min number will never be saved in the        variable.. it will always have garbage
int maximum;

int big=0;
int small=0;
int count;


cin>>n;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    cin>>a[i];  
    minimum=min(a[i],minimum);  
    maximum=max(a[i],maximum); 
}

for(int j=0; j<n; j++) //ex: input 3 1 2 3 1, big=2, small= 2, count= 2x2= 4
{
    if(a[j]==maximum)
    {big++;} 

    if(a[j]==minimum)
    {small++;}
}
count= big * small;

if(minimum==maximum)  //ex: input 1 1 1 1 1 , there are 10 probabilities = (5x4)/2
    count= n*(n-1)/2;  

cout<<maximum-minimum<<" "<<count<<endl; 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem states that `2 <= n <= 2 * 10^5`, but your `a` array can hold only 1000 integers!

Hence, you have an index out of bounds once you `cin >> a[1000];`.